# U.S. personal debt ratio distribution?

Tags: usa, economics

Where can I find the distribution (histogram) of personal debt ratios in the United States?

Comment: I'd start with the 3 major credit bureaus and see if they have aggregate information for sale: trw.com transunion.com equifax.com - - I'm pretty sure creditsesame.com creditkarma.com quizzle.com and similar have this info for free, but not sure if it applies to everyone or just their users.

Comment: https://www.statista.com has debt data, but I can't find debt ratio distributions/histograms.